# FirefoxのSpidermonkeyのコードの読み方

Tags: c++, firefox, ecmascript-6

C++の勉強のためにFirefoxのJS Engineである、SpiderMonkeyのコードを読みたいと思っているのですが、どこから読み始めればいいのか迷っています。
functionやobjectなどのJSの基本的なところや、ES6で新しく入るclassの実装などが気になっています。
将来的にはjsの実装みたいなことをやりたいと考えているのですが、js/srcのどこから始めればいいのでしょうか?

Comment: ある機能を実装している箇所のコードを知りたいとかなら回答できますが、ただ読みたいというだけでは、お好きなところから読んでくださいとしか言えないと思います。

Comment: 具体的な箇所について追記しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

名前のままですが、functionは`src/jsfun.cpp`、Objectは`src/jsobj.cpp`に実装があります。arrayなども同様です。

classについては、基本的に文法が追加されているだけなので機能としての実装は存在しません。強いて言うなら、`src/frontend/Parser.cpp`でしょうか。